# Asked about graduation of music graduate school

Tags: theory

When you graduate from jazz department or popular music graduate school except classical department.

Graduation conditions are thesis or graduation work.
Do you have many disadvantages in the future if you do not graduate from a thesis?
The paper is too difficult.
My graduation is to create a single album.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to teach, no-one cares if a musician has a diploma or not, let alone the details of how he got it.  And as you find a dissertation 'too hard', I guess you aren't heading for an academic career path.

Comment: Not a lot seem to care even if you want to teach...

Comment: @Tim in some countries schools require you to have a specific certificate that says you are allowed to teach (in the Netherlands "lesbevoegdheid") which you can obtain as part of your studies (optional, depending on the institution)  but it's also possible (and reasonably common) to get it later following a short part-time course. For free-lance teachers this is of course not required.